# Entering data into an excel sheet with PnPjs

Tags: excel, react, pnpjs

I want to create a webpart for a sharepoint site, that allows users to enter an identifier about the sheet then using PnPjs i want to allow users to enter that data into the sheet. I would have assumed that I can embed just the default excel view into the web part but I cant find any information on this.

I also want to know if this is possible, do macros function accordingly?